In the late 70s as a teen I read a book about a journalist who did a TV interview. In the interview he doubted the existence of Christ
In the late '70s as a teen I read a book about a journalist who did a TV interview. In the interview he said he doubted the existence of Christ. Later he got accosted and knocked out, and when he wakes up he is in Christ's time.
What was the name of this book?

possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44980/time-travel-story-book-similar-to-behold-the-man-but-closer-to-the-bible
